# Transmit second sk_buff using current virtual device

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I modify the transmit function (`ndo_start_xmit`) of a virtual network device which gets an `struct sk_buff skb_one` as input.

At one point in the transmission flow I generate a second `struct sk_buff skb_second`. This one should go through the same flow `skb_one` was going, so it should be sent by the virtual device I am currently in. Furthermore it should be sent **after** `skb_one`.

I thought about two different methods. One is modyfing the queue `skb_one` is in:

```
    skb_second->next = skb_one->next;
    skb_second->prev = skb_one;
    skb_one->next = skb_frag;
```

Using this approach it is sent after `skb_one` but it is not going through the transmission flow of the virtual network device.

The second approach is just using

```
dev_queue_xmit(skb_second);
```

With this approach the `skb_second` goes through the transmission flow "again", but it is sent before `skb_one`.

Is there a possibility to reach both goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dev_queue_xmit` would eventually try to get the device's `xmit_lock`, but it would fail because being in `ndo_start_xmit` you should already hold it.

So the frame would be queued to run in the `NET_TX_SOFTIRQ` *after* `skb_one` is sent out and `ndo_start_xmit` has returned.

Am I missing something?